# Live cycle make a form so that it can't be changed by the end user

Tags: adobe, livecycle

I created a form in LiveCycle and I want to make it so a user can edit and save the form with adobe reader. I have that part my concern is that if they have acrobat pro and Livecycle they can open the form in Acrobat pro hit the forms button and start to make changes to the form in live cycle. Is there a way to make it so that the end user can't open the file in livecycle to make changes?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Reader Extensions](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/readerextensions/) which is a service provided in Live Cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can set password protection and user permissions in designer by going to:
File -> Form Properties -> PDF Security